# Token authentication and SSL

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

I'm relatively new to this area of securing API. Most of my career was in developing internal products for the use of the organization, or joining a product that has already implemented security (which usually does not change)

When reading about JWT and Identity server, I understood the role of signing and the need to separate authorization and authentication. But, one thing strikes me as odd:
If my user is about to get a signed token and use it to authenticate himself, and there is a "Man in the middle", listening and copying that token, could he impersonate my user? (I believe the answer is yes)
So my best option here is to use SSL on every call to my API. The token being temporary and all is not much less of a threat to security.

So, my question here is:
If I end up using SSL on  my API calls, what is the signing good for? with SSL the traffic is hidden anyway and no one could tamper with it. The browser can possibly use the username and password as plain text and they won't be exposed.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all boils down to what purpose JWT serves in [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) protocol (OIDC).

In OIDC, [ID token](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) is a JWT. And if you go through [RFC7519 - JSON Web Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519), then you come across [Trust Decisions section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-11.1).

> The contents of a JWT cannot be relied upon in a trust decision
> unless its contents have been cryptographically secured and bound to
> the context necessary for the trust decision

From OIDC perspective, trust decision is to authenticate the end user based on claims contained in the ID token. This can be only done if validation adhere to JWT specification. So basically it is a requirement by OIDC protocol and JWT specification.

Now about SSL. OIDC contains several other calls required to obtain final token response. These calls contain client identifiers, secrets and authorization code (depending on the flow). OIDC is built on OAuth 2.0 and OAuth 2.0 [mandate SSL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.9) (TLS being the new name). Thus OIDC too require SSL.

In combination, SSL (TLS) prevents attacks during request and responses flow in wire. And JWT's signature guarantee token's authenticity independent of how it was received or which component of your application process it.